# fade-in a div on a ScrollTop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

First off I'm sorry for my bad English, but i'm Italian.

Now it's time for the question: I have a div, with class `hideme`, and I want to animate it when the page is scrolled down.

I have read and followed a question on this site, but it doesn't work.

The HTML code of the page is:

```
<section class="maps"><div id="aboutus" class="bgParallax" data-speed="15">
  <span class="space"></span>
  <div class="b-text">
    <p>Stupisciti.</p>
    [one_third]
     <div class="hideme">
      <h3 class="parallax"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i> La TUA pubblicità</h3>
     </div>
    [/one_third]
  </div>
</section>
```

The CSS code is:

```
.bgParallax {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight: 100;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%; 
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.maps {
    height: 400px;
}

.b-text {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.b-text p {
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.hideme {
    opacity:0;
}

.parallax {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.parallax i {
    color: #05B5FA;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px;
    -moz-text-stroke: 1px;
    -o-text-stroke: 1px;
    -ms-text-stroke: 1px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

while the jQuery code is:

```
$(window).scroll( function(){
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){
        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
                }
        }); 
    });
});
```

I don't know if this info is important, but I've put the code into a script tag in the body flow.

Thanks very much for all the help

Comment: Could you please make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something similar with what you have? And what effect are you looking for?

Comment: The effect which i would obtain is this: http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qaD/

Comment: While my example is this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZP64f/